# Find a substring that appears before a word in a string upto a number

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a string :

```
"abc mysql 23 rufos kanso engineer"
```

I want the regex to output the string before the word "engineer" till it sees a number.

That is the regex should output :

```
23 rufos kanso
```

Another example:

String:

```
def grusol defno 1635 minos kalopo, ruso engineer okas puno"
```

I want the regex to output the string before the word "engineer" till it sees a number.

That is the regex should output :

```
1635 minos kalopo, ruso
```

I am able to achieve this by a series of regex .

Can I do this in one shot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern I'd use: `((\d+)(?!.*\d).*)engineer` -- it looks for the latest digit and goes from there.

Something similar to `(\d.*)engineer` would also work but only if there's only one digit in the string.

---

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '123 abc mysql 23 rufos kanso engineer'
>>> pattern = r'((\d+)(?!.*\d).*)engineer'
>>> re.search(pattern, string).group(1)
'23 rufos kanso '
>>>
```

---

#### Edit

In case there are digits after the 'engineer' part, the pattern mentioned above does not work, as you have pointed out in the comment. I tried to solve it, but honestly I couldn't come up with a new pattern (sorry).

The workaround I could suggest is, assuming 'engineer' is still the 'key' word, splitting your initial string by said word.

Here is the illustration of what I mean:

```
>>> string = '123 abc mysql 23 rufos kanso engineer 1234 b65 de'
>>> string.split('engineer')
['123 abc mysql 23 rufos kanso ', ' 1234 b65 de']
>>> string.split('engineer')[0] 
'123 abc mysql 23 rufos kanso '

# hence, there would be no unexpected digits

>>> s = string.split('engineer')[0]
>>> pattern = r'((\d+)(?!.*\d).*)'
>>> re.search(pattern, s).group(1)
'23 rufos kanso '
```

Comment: Thanks.

This works, But if  the string has a number at the end it doesn't work

Example

string = '123 abc mysql 23 rufos kanso engineer 1234 b65 de'

Answer (score 0):

Use [`positive look-ahead`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/7177029) to match until the word engineer preceded by a digit.

[`The regex`](https://regex101.com/r/p6Nycm/1/) - `(?=\d)(.+)(?=engineer)`

Just to get an idea:

```
import re
pattern = r"(?=\d)(.+)(?=engineer)"
input = [ "\"def grusol defno 1635 minos kalopo, ruso engineer okas puno\"", "\"abc mysql 23 rufos kanso engineer\"" ]

matches = []

for item in input:
    matches.append(re.findall(pattern, item))
```

Outputting:

```
[['1635 minos kalopo, ruso '], ['23 rufos kanso ']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [site](https://regex101.com/). It is great to play around with regex and it explains every steps.
Here is a solution to your problem: [link](https://regex101.com/r/ghFzBL/2)